# Is $\frac{0}{\infty}$ indeterminate?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, indeterminate-forms

I have been searching for an answer for this for half an hour and I can't seem to find one. I've lots of information about other combinations of $0$ and $\infty$ but I haven't seen anything that says whether $\frac{0}{\infty}$ is indeterminate?

Comment: I think it equals $0$?

Comment: What do you need that information for? Usually claims involving the word "indeterminate" are just a way to make something simple and straightforward sound mysterious and impenetrable. Do you have an expression you want to find the limit of? Show that instead of confusing yourself with unhelpful concepts such as "$\frac0\infty$" or "indeterminate".

Comment: Math is not about memorizing facts you don't understand. Rather than searching for an answer to this for half an hour, you should have attempted to discover an answer for yourself! This involves thinking and understanding what's going on, rather than just following rules you've been fed.

Comment: Well what is $lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{k^n}{\sqrt(n)}$ when $k < 1$?

Comment: Zero. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @anon I always try and learn, not memorize. But indeterminate forms are like facts, it's just the ones I've seen mentioned don't deal with my situation.

Comment: @csss: If $k\in(0,1)$, then $k^n$ is always less than $1$, so your sequence is strictly smaller than $1/\sqrt n$, which clearly tends to $0$.

Comment: Or alternatively, the sequence is strictly smaller than $k^n$, which tends to $0$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Cheers. Thanks to anon too.

Comment: @csss: No "indeterminate forms" are not facts to be memorized without understanding! They are just occult-sounding ways of expressing the conclusion that "such-and-such information is not _in itself_ sufficient to determine a limit". If you had started thinking instead of spending time searching for a predigested fact, you could have discovered for yourself whether you have enough information to find the limit or not.

Answer (score 4):

This quotient is zero. This is true whether you mean projective infinity or extended positive infinity.

Since you say "indeterminate", I assume you're talking about *limit forms*. Well, division is continuous and defined at $0/\infty$, so this is, indeed, *not* an indeterminate form.

This is actually pretty easy to show that this limit form works out to $0$ by the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit: you should try to do so on your own. (and ask a new question here on MSE about it if you get stuck)

Comment: Where do you find a definition of division that makes it defined at $0/\infty$?

Comment: @Henning: Anyplace that talks about arithmetic in the projective or extended real lines.

Comment: For a specific example, see Priestley's *Introduction to Complex Analysis: Second Edition*, p.19., where $\frac{a}{\infty}=0$ for all $a\in\mathbb{C}$ **by definition** (or, rather, by convention) in the extended complex plane $\bar{\mathbb{C}}$.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to rephrase the question like this:

If $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = 0$ and $g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to a$ then does limit $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)/g(x)$ exist?

The answer is yes it does and $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)/g(x) = 0$. It is best not to think of indeterminate forms as numbers and writing undefined expressions like $0/0, \infty/\infty, 0/\infty,\infty/0, \text{etc..}$ is a source of major confusion (although almost all the calculus text write in such notation and are guilty for spreading confusion). It is always better to state explicitly what one means by these forms by writing them in form of a limit.

Answer (score -1):

$$[\frac{0}{\infty}] = [0 \cdot \frac{1}{\infty}] = [0 \cdot 0]= 0$$

so it isn't.