# Computing $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\tan^2(x))}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I have to find :
$$l=\lim\limits_{x \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\tan^2(x))}$$
As both $\ln(x)$ and $\ln(\tan^2(x))$ $\rightarrow 0$ when $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$ I can use L'Hopital's rule. We have that:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\tan^2(x))}\right)' =& \frac{1/x}{1/(\sin^2(x)/\cos^2(x)) \cdot 2 \cdot (\sin(x)/\cos(x)) \cdot 1/(\cos^2(x))} \\
 =& \frac{1/x}{2/(\cos(x)\sin(x))}\\ =&\frac{\cos(x)\sin(x)}{2x}
\end{align}
$$

and if I differentiate this once again I have that

$$\frac{-\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{2} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$$ when $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$

Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: Neither $ln(x)$ nor $ln(tan(x^2))$ go to $0$ as x approaches $0$. They go to $-\infty$

Comment: Ye sure, thanks!

Comment: Don't use L'Hospital's unless differentiation of numerator and denominator is available from memory.

Comment: @Mathias, there is an answer providing/offering you the most efficient and elementary method, without using _L'Hospital's rule_. If you find it useful, make sure you upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{\ln\left(\tan ^2 x\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln x}{\ln\left(\tan x\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(1+\frac{\ln\left(\frac{x}{\tan x}\right)}{\ln(\tan x)}\right)$$

As already mentioned:

$$\color{red}{\text{standard limit from the table:}}\;\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\tan x}=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\ln(\tan x)=-\infty$$
$$\implies\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{x}{\tan x}\right)}{\ln(\tan x)}=0\implies L=\frac{1}{2}$$

If the above confuses you, I highly recommend to [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/562328/721644)

You may [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3504422/721644)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Luke the given limit is in $\frac {-\infty} {-\infty}$ form.

Otherwise what you have done is correct but you don't have to apply L'Hopital's rule  a second time. Just use the facts that $\cos x \to 1$ and $\frac {\sin x } x \to 1$.

Comment: Glad you edited to include @Luke's observation.  (Maybe slow down, and get it right the first time around, no?)

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+} } \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\tan^2(x))} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+} } \frac{\ln(x)}{2\ln(\tan(x))} = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+} } \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\tan(x))} = \text{L'Hospital's rule} = \\ \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+} } \frac {\frac {1}{x}}{\frac {1}{\tan x} \frac{1}{\cos^2x}} = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+} } \frac {\sin x \cos x}{x} = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+} } \frac {\sin x}{x} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+} } {\cos x} = \frac{1}{2}.$$
$$$$

**An edited answer**. Thanks for the comment @LostInSpace

Comment: Anton, you made a mistake, you have $\sin (x) \cos ( x) $ at the denominator : $$ \frac{1}{2} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+} } \frac {\sin x\cos x}{x}  $$